# Spring BlazeDS + Flex + JBoss Project setup in eclipse using Maven

Tags: apache-flex, spring, maven-2, blazeds, project-setup

I would like to know how to proceed to set up a work environment in order to develop Spring BlazeDS applications. Those server applications are meant to be accessed via AMF remoting from some client Flex application.

Actually I have Maven and m2eclipse set up and working, local JBoss v6.0M2 running, Flex 4 plugin installed.

Ideally, I would like to know how to create an eclipse project in which I can have both server (Java) and client (Flex) code and be able to deploy everything in one click to JBoss. Maybe there is a special Maven archetype for this setup? If not, I will be happy if someone can provide step by step instructions to setup all this stuff.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [`maven-blazeds-spring-archetype`](http://code.google.com/p/maven-blazeds-spring-archetype/) archetype (and its [GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/maven-blazeds-spring-archetype/wiki/GettingStarted) guide) and at the article that inspired the archetype: [The Flex, Spring, and BlazeDS full stack – Part 1: Creating a Flex module](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/fullstack_pt1.html).

**Update:** I just tried the archetype and, indeed, it need some tweaks. Here are the steps:

1. Create a project from the remote repository

   ```
   mvn archetype:generate -DartifactId=<your artifactId> -DarchetypeCatalog=http://maven-blazeds-spring-archetype.googlecode.com/svn/maven2/
   ```
2. `cd` into the created project and modify the location of Sonatype's repository in  `./pom.xml`. Replace http://svn.sonatype.org/flexmojos/repository by http://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/forge/ (there are 2 occurences to replace).
3. Update the version of the `<flex-mojos.version>` in `app-flex/pom.xml`, replace `2.0M8` with the latest `2.0.3`.
4. Perform the initial setup

   ```
   mvn clean install -DtemplateURI=folder:html-template
   ```
5. Follow the rest of the steps of the [GettingStarted](http://code.google.com/p/maven-blazeds-spring-archetype/wiki/GettingStarted).

Comment: I found another archetype : flex-blazeds-spring-archetype but for some reason, I can't deploy it in my JBoss server correctly, or maybe I just don't know how. I also need to debug my flex application in Eclipse, but don't know where to put remoting informations.
I will try the one you suggest now.

Comment: Did you try the archetype you provided? I can't even create the project because of missing dependencies (flex mojos 2.0M8). Besides, there is some mysterious dependency to jdk1.6.0_10 in .classpath. 
I hope you can help.

Comment: This archetype just doesn't work for me. If it does for you, I would appreciate step by step instructions to have a Hello World application running in JBoss or even Tomcat, whatever.

Comment: @Adnan I gave you step by step instructions, I don't see what more I can do, especially since you didn't explain what doesn't work (if it works on my machine, it should work on yours). Maybe post the errors here http://pastie.org/ and put the link in a comment or update your question with it.

Comment: You've gotten me farther than anyone!  (I'm new to Maven also).  Would you please take a look at this stack trace? http://pastie.org/1480977